# bash read loop premature EOF

Tags: bash, loops

In the following code I expect the `while` loop to execute three times, once for each matching line in the input `build.cfg` file.  This is in fact what *does* happen, but only if I comment out the guts of the case blocks -- i.e. the subshells starting with `( mkdir work ...` and `( cd product ...`.

When executed as shown below, the loop executes only once (for `BUILDTYPE == build`)

When run with -x, it's clear that the shell loops back and executes the `read` but gets EOF, as there are no errors and execution continues with the `setStatus` line.

Clearly, something in the subshell is interfering with the outer pipeline file descriptors.  Can someone explain exactly why this is happening?

```
egrep "^\s*$BRANCH" $ETC/build.cfg | ( while read BRANCH TARGET SVNSRC SVNTAG BUILDTYPE DISTTYPE DISTARGS
do
    echo ----- $TARGET $BUILDTYPE
    pushd $WORKSPACE/$BUILDUID
    case $BUILDTYPE in
        build)
            echo ">>> BUILD"
            ( mkdir work
              cp product/buildcontrol/buildConfig_example.xml work/defaultBuildConfig.xml
              cd product
              ./build installer-all )
            ;;
        tma)
            echo ">>> TMA"
            ( cd product
              ./build -f ..${SVNTAG}build.xml )
            ;;
        *)
            ;;
    esac
    popd
done )
setStatus 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some command should be reading from *stdin*. Try running the commands inside the loop with *stdin* redirected:

```
./build installer-all < /dev/null

...

./build -f ..${SVNTAG}build.xml  < /dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks.  Both you and AH had the righr answer, and you were first by a couple of minutes, so you get the "accept".

Answer (score 3):

If anything inside the subshell eats your input, then you have several choices:

- Check what inside `./build` wants some input and supply that input or
- cut of standard input of the subshells by using `( ... ) < /dev/null`

Comment: Interesting... I know that `./build` does not read any input.  However, since I didn't write it, and it invokes ANT under the covers, I can't be sure it doesn't do something with the file descriptor internally.  I will try your suggestion.